# Should I put actors in the Domain-Model/Class-Diagram?

Tags: c#, java, oop, domain-model

When designing both the domain-model and class-diagrams I am having some trouble understanding what to put in them.

I'll give an example of what I mean:

I am doing a vacations scheduler program, that has an `Administrator` and `End-Users`. The `Administrator` does a couple of things like registering `End-Users` in the program, changing their previleges, etc. The `End-User` can choose his vacations days, etc.

I initially defined an `Administrator` and `End-User` as concepts in the domain-model, and  later as classes in the class-diagram.
In the class-diagram, both classes ended up having a couple of methods like

```
Administrator.RegisterNewUser();
Administrator.UnregisterUser(int id);
```

etc.

Only after some time I realised that actually both `Administrator` and `End-User` are actors, and maybe I got this design totally wrong. Instead of filling Administrator and End-User classes with methods to do what my Use-Cases request, I could define other classes from the domain to do them, and have controllers handle the Use-Cases(actually, I decided to do one for each Use-Case). I could have a `UserDatabase.RegisterNewUser()` and `UserDatabase.UnregisterUser(int id);`, for example, instead of having those methods on the `Administrator` class.

The idea would be to try to think of the whole vacation-scheduler as a "closed-program" that has a set of features and doesn't bother with things such as authentication, that should be internal/protected, being that the only public things I'd let the outside world see would be its controllers.

Is this the right approach? Or am I getting this totally wrong? Is it generally bad idea to put Actors in the domain-model/class-diagrams? What are good rules of thumb for this?

My lecturer is following [Applying UML and Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131489062), which I find awful, so I'd like to know where I could look up more info on this described actor-models situation.

I'm still a bit confused about all of this, as this new approach is radically different from anything I've done before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not say that your design, as you speculate, is totally wrong, in fact Administrator and End-User are valid domain objects that should be represented somehow in the Class Diagrams. Just because you identify those two entities as actors doesn't mean they should be excluded from the Domain, remember, your domain is your scope, or "relevant context", that is, the set of useful objects that play a relevant role in your solution.

You may start with basic objects that comprise your model, just write them down, without further analysis, like brain storming...

- Vacation
- Location
- Travel Agent
- Schedule
- User
- Reservation
- Reservation Service (This can be an interface for accessing the vacation reservation stuff)

Then try to establish the relationships between those objects, if you can not find any relationship that means you are not choosing the right objects, if they are part of the same problem domain then they must be related somehow.

After some time, you will discover that there are objects missing, try to encapsulate as much as possible, and represent the correct abstractions, Design Patterns might help you out with that.

When every possible object is represented with all its properties and methods, then you should have a fully, although not yet finished, functional design.

I know you should have a lot of theory in your mind, so get going, without fear, I myself have used this approach successfully many times at work.

Finally get a copy of [UML Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687)

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

I think you should learn more about domain modeling and process of getting from use cases to class diagrams. Actors as classifiers can be part of class diagrams, however for class diagrams used for analysis and design are modeling the system you develop and an actor is external entity. When you are using use cases and use case diagrams, the goal is to identify functional and non-functional requrements, therefore define the scope of the system to develop and external entities - roles or systems - interacting with the system you are developing. In use case diagrams you can find sometimes a box representing system boundary, which encompasses all use cases, which will be realized in your system, but actors are out of the box. When domain modeling, you usually forget about the system altogether, because you want to capture the way the domain works. Often special diagrams and modeling elements are used for domain modeling. As I said, the point is to understand the domain in which the system will be used. Class diagrams in the analysis and design phase describe the system you are developing, so no actors can be inside.